# Ruby get numerals from a string

Tags: ruby, arrays, regex

I have the following string from which I want to extract numerals into an array

```
b="yesterday: 136.00. current: *143.00*. change: *-7.00*. change_2: *5.15%*. high: 143.00. low: 143.00"
```

So I first did,

```
c = b.split(". ")
d = c.map{ |x| x.scan(/[\d\.-]+/)[0] }.map(&:to_f)
```

However d returns:

```
[136.0, 143.0, -7.0, 2.0, 143.0, 143.0]
```

Instead of

```
[136.0, 143.0, -7.0, 5.15, 143.0, 143.0]
```

Comment: Where did you get such a weird string?

Comment: I believe you are retrieving the `2` from `change_2` instead of `*5.15%*`

Comment: @Robin...... Yeah that's what happening. How do I retrieve 5.15 instead of 2

Comment: The string format is not changing? only numbers?

Comment: the simplest way:) d = c.map{ |x| x.scan(/[\d\.-]+/).last }.map(&:to_f)

Comment: @BroiSatse .... from [this](https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1ncyK8uXoeLobVkdiSKQcYJr2joK_uN5QSBB3814GKaw/od6/public/values) rss feed

Comment: @crackedmind ,,, string format never changes. Anyway.....Adeptus method worked fine even when I tried using negative digits

Comment: @chris ........ Well, my suggestion to use scanf module from stdlib

Comment: BTW, not need to escape the dot in a character class: `[\d.-]` will work the same.

Comment: @chris - this rss feed returns coma separated list, is it a typo in your question then?

Comment: No.... I have used the feedjira gem to fetch and parse the data and then taken the @entry.content object which returns that string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just:

```
b.scan(/(?<=[ *])-?\d[\d.]+/).map(&:to_f)
# => [136.0, 143.0, -7.0, 5.15, 143.0, 143.0]
```

Comment: You added the `to_f` call later, didn't you? YOu should adjust the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
b.scan(/-?\d+.\d{2}[%*.]?/).map(&:to_f)
#=> [136.0, 143.0, -7.0, 5.15, 143.0, 143.0]
```

Comment: This returns numerical data but with asterisks at the end

Comment: ...which the `to_f` call makes disappear.

Answer (score -1):

For something this complex I think you should use a regex, so something like this

/^yesterday: ([0-9+]) .. / =~ b

you can use [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/) to help figure out the regex

Since it appears like you are trying to parse a fairly complex string and get a specific set of numbers from the "fields" in that string, a good way to do this is with a regex.

One of the best tools to determine exactly what that regex needs to be is Rubular.

If you are unfamiliar with parsing a string using regex , please see the Regex class in the docs
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html

For example the following regex would get each of those numbers into a corresponding variable.  The reqex method is a little more complex but also shows what you are intending to do.

```
^yesterday: (?<yesterday>[-]*\d+\.\d+)\. current: \*(?<current>[-]*\d+\.\d+)\*\. change: \*(?<change>[-]*\d+\.\d+)\*\. change_2: \*(?<change_2>[-]*\d+\.\d+)%\*\. high: (?<high>[-]*\d+\.\d+)\. low: (?<low>[-]*\d+\.\d+)$
```